# Can't download GoogleService-Info.plist file

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, google-analytics, crashlytics

I'm trying to setup Google Analytics for my new iOS app, when following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/).

It instructs me to click the "Get A Configuration File" button, but that button just sends me to another page that has a spinning, nothing ever happens. I already have a property setup in Analytics for web and a view setup for mobile.

Can anyone share the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file with me so I can attempt to manually fill in the details of the file and add it to my project?

Comment: It should look like this https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/mock-GoogleService-Info.plist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sanjana I decided to look at Google's web code and found they have an X-Frame error.

So the url you can visit is https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=cloudconsole&osid=1&passiv…collection/ios/v3/app?configured%253Dtrue&hl=en#add-config&cntlbl=Continue

Comment: weird because I followed same link again "Get A Configuration File" and I could download second time.

Comment: Yup, I had tried closing the browser and opening it again, even tried 2 other browsers just to see, that's when I got thinking that they must have a bug in their js, so I looked in the console and found they had linked to resources on a subdomain which violates JavaScripts cross-linking rule.

Comment: Oh okay..I didn't have to do that much...not sure how but I could download next time...anyways now you have it :)

Answer (score 6):

It happened with me also. If you close everything and follow that link it worked for me next time. You can try to do that. Below is the link of sample plist file, of course I replaced tracking id, bundle id and app id to strings from original values. Hope it helps.

[Sample Google Plist file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mc0fakwrxetrao6/GoogleService-Info.plist?dl=0)

Comment: Handling multiple google accounts was messing up the downloading. Thank you for idea.

Answer (score 4):

Generally in iOS

1) Create your project in Firebase console https://console.firebase.google.com

[image]

Click add project and follow steps.

2) Now open this link to get **GoogleService-Info.plist** file

https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

-->Click Get Started

[image]

-->Select your project
Ex: CloudFirestoreSwift

--> Now select domain Ex: iOS

[image]

-->Now add app bundle id then **GoogleService-Info.plist** file will be generate, download it and complete the steps if required.

**NOTE:** Please don't change file name. It's must be **GoogleService-Info.plist**

[image]

If you already generated GoogleService-Info.plist file. Now select your project and go project settings.

[image]

--> Go General tab, you can find GoogleService-Info.plist file here download it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Steps for getting configuration if your first time login to google developer account.**

```
1. Open google developer console.
2. Login to developer console.
3. Create project with valid name.
4. Enable google analytics. 
5. Then get the configuration file.
```

Comment: This helped me. I only needed to create the project.

Answer (score 3):

The download link is not always immediately visible and you have to scroll up to get it, I happen to press next before downloading and I missed the opportunity to download the file.

I prefer the automatically generated file as I am lazy (aren't we all)

So, follow these steps

1. Go to https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/
2. Scroll down to `Get a configuration file`
3. When prompted for the app name and bundle Id, just use the drop down menu and you'll find your previously created app details there.
4. Proceed to the next screen `Continue to: Choose and Configure Services`
5. Select your service, note that your previously selected ones will have a green arrow (Analytics in the case below)
   [image: Select & configure services]
6. Select `Generate configuration file`
7. You'll be given an opportunity to download the file again.

[image: Download and install configuration file]

Voila!

Comment: I get the never ending spinner after clicking my Platform (iOS in this case) :(

Answer (score 2):

You need to login on https://console.developers.google.com create your first application, then go back to https://developers.google.com/mobile/add the website will now work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Installing `Ignore X-Frame headers` plugin on Chrome made this bug vanish

Answer (score 1):

Same here, I got following invalid json file:

```
)]}'
{"status":401,"message":"Invalid authuser parameter"}
```

and that is resolved by **clearing cookies on google.com** on your browser.